# how to make infinte loop to return sleep if no new input to predict

Tags: python, pandas, csv, machine-learning

this is my code below I am trying to predict continues input to my csv file then read it through pandas with just 1 chunk then go to the other row until the file is finish I want the script to still running waiting for new row to code and predict

my code

```
for row in pd.read_csv('test1.csv', chunksize=1):
        GB = 'GB_MODEL_PKL'
        GB_model = pickle.load(open(GB, 'rb')) # loading the binary .pkl
        result = GB_model.predict(row)
        time.sleep(1)
        if result == 0:
            print('benign')
        elif result ==1:
            print('suspicious')
```

I have tried this but the issue chunksize will give us another datatype that is not dataframe

```
counter = 0
while True :
    try :     
        row = pd.read_csv('test.csv', chunksize=1)
        row = row[newx]
        GB = 'GB_MODEL_PKL'
        GB_model = pickle.load(open(GB, 'rb')) # loading the binary .pkl
        result = GB_model.predict(row)
        print(result)
        counter += 1
    except:
        sleep(2)
        print('sleep')
        continue
```

Comment: When you iterate over a pandas DataFrame naively like that, what you get are columns, not rows.  You may want to use `.iterrows()` instead.  Does your model absolutely expect pandas data?  Could you not just read the CSV using the `csv` model and pass the rows that way?

Comment: Do you HAVE to reload the pickle every time through the loop?  Unless it retains state, you should be able to move those two lines out of the loop.  And why do you have "sleep" calls in there at all?

Comment: .iterrows() is will conflict with . predict even though the data types are same but it will print the rwos as two col one with feature name and one with feature value .

Comment: Indeed I remove the load pickle . For sleep I want for the loop to wait for the new input to predict but i am facing the issue with the second code the loop will be endless but will not stop a d wait for the new rows .

Comment: `row = row[newx]` doesn't work because row is a `TextFileReader`, so you're getting an exception, which you are throwing away.  You shouldn't use a blanket `except` in any case, and you shouldn't use `try`/`except` at all until you know the code works.  Try using `row = list(pd.read_csv('test.csv', chunksize=1))`.  That will let you index by row number.

Comment: yes you are indeed right for the textfilereader , the issue with using list(pd.read_csv) I an able to declare the new features in row = row(newx) hence I will not be able to predict . I just need to run the first for loop and keep it running waiting for new rows that will come one by my other tool